# Division operation on asymptotic notation

Tags: complexity-theory

Suppose

```
S(n) = Big-Oh(f(n)) & T(n) = Big-Oh(f(n))
```

both `f(n)` identically belongs from the same class.

My ques is: Why `S(n)/T(n) = Big-Oh(1)` is incorrect?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean by "both f(n) identically belongs from the same class".

Comment: Thanks Jason for adding that tag.

Comment: S(n) = 10*n^2 + n*log(n) + 10 & T(n) = 3*n^2 + 2*n + 1 and f(n) = n^2 denote the class (or set) contains all functions of running time n^2 with some constant multiplier.  

"Both f(n) identically belongs from the same class" - I mean to say that S(n) & T(n) belongs to n^2 class ignore that constant multiplier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider `S(n) = n^2` and `T(n) = n`. Then both `S` and `T` are `O(n^2)` but `S(n) / T(n) = n` which is not `O(1)`.

Here's another example. Consider `S(n) = sin(n)` and `T(n) = cos(n)`. Then `S` and `T` are `O(1)` but `S(n) / T(n) = tan(n)` is not `O(1)`. This second example is important because it shows that even if you have a tight bound, the conclusion can still fail.

Why is this happening? Because the obvious "proof" completely fails. The obvious "proof" is the following. There are constants `C_S` and `C_T` and `N_S` and `N_T` where `n >= N_S` implies `|S(n)| <= C_S * f(n)` and `n >= N_T` implies `|T(n)| <= C_T * f(n)`. Let `N = max(N_S, N_T)`. Then for `n >= N` we have

```
|S(n) / T(n)| <= (C_S * f(n)) / (C_T * f(n)) = C_S / C_T.
```

**This is completely and utterly wrong.** It is not the case that `|T(n)| <= C_T * f(n)` implies that `1 / |T(n)| <= 1 / (C_T * f(n))`. In fact, what is true is that `1 / |T(n)| >= 1 / (C_T * f(n))`. The inequality reverses, and that suggests there is a serious problem with the "theorem." The intuitive idea is that if `T` is "small" (i.e., bounded) then `1 / T` is "big." But we're trying to show that `1 / T` is "small" and we just can't do that. As our counterexamples show, the "proof" is fatally flawed.

However, there is a theorem here that is true. Namely, if `S(n)` is `O(f(n))` and `T(n)` is `Ω(f(n))`, then `S(n) / T(n)` is `O(1)`. The above "proof" works for this theorem (thanks are due to [Simone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323349/division-operation-on-asymptotic-notation/7323520#7323520) for the idea to generalize to this statement).

Comment: +1 for picking the exact same example as me at the same time ;-)

Comment: @sepp2k: Wow, five second difference on posting time! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one counter example:

Let's say `f(n) = n^2`, `S(n) = n^2` and `T(n) = n`. Now both S and T are in `O(f(n))` (you have to remember that `O(n^2)` is a superset of `O(n)`, so everything that's in `O(n)` is also in `O(n^2)`), but `U(n) = S(n)/T(n) = n^2/n = n` is definitely not in `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others explained S(n) / T(n) is not generally O(1).

Your doubt probably derive from the confusion between O and Θ; in fact if:

```
S(n) = Θ(n)      and      T(n) = Θ(n)
```

then the following is true:

```
S(n) / T(n) = Θ(1)  and thus S(n) / T(n) = O(1)
```

Comment: Well, more generally, if `S` is `O(f)` and `T` is `Ω(f)` then `S / T` is `O(1)`.

Comment: @Simone Can u please explain in details?

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that this is wrong if you plug some actual functions into your formula, e.g.

```
S(n) = n^2
T(n) = n
f(n) = n^2

S(n) / T(n) = n
n != O(1)
```

Comment: In that case the statement will be true. But mathematically speaking, if a statement is demonstrated to be false even for one set of params, it is considered false in general.

Comment: Thank you. The statement is generally false and true for only some particular class.