# Big O for division operator to find big O

Tags: big-o

I have a question about big O (data structure & algorithm)

I have this expression :
100n/(2n+1)

and I need figure out what is the dominant term and the big O(.)

I solved it like this , the dominant term is : 100n
and the big O is : O(n) . my question is that right ? or with the division the n cancelled and the answer should be : O(1) ? .

Comment: Have you tried graphing it and seeing which curve it most closely approximates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division operation on asymptotic notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323349/division-operation-on-asymptotic-notation)

Comment: `O(1)` implies that the algorithm executes in constant time as it's not dependent upon `n`; that is not true in your case.

Comment: in arithmetic terms it would be `50 - 50/(2n+1)`. since big-O is about "asymptotic" and "large value for N" result will be really-really close to constant value of 50 or O(1)